# Can you store multiple values to one variable

Tags: java

I was trying to create a GPA calculator, but I ran into an issue. I'm trying to use one variable to store different values. For example, I want my code to go like this:

Enter the amount of AP Classes:

and then I want the user to also name each class, so like:

Name of AP Class 1
Name of AP Class 2.. and so on

I want the user to type in the name of the AP Class and the percent they have in that class. How can I do this without knowing the number of AP Classes?

Here is my code:

```
    System.out.print("Enter the number of classes you have: ");
    numOfClass = Keyboard.readInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the amount of AP Classes: ");
    numOfAP = Keyboard.readInt();

    if (numOfAP > 0)
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of AP Class " + (numOfAPNamed + 1) + ": ");
            nameAP = Keyboard.readString();

            System.out.print("Enter grade (in percentage) of AP Class " + (numOfAPNamed + 1) + ": ");
            gradeAP = Keyboard.readDouble();

            System.out.println();

            numOfAPNamed++;
        }while (numOfAPNamed != numOfAP);

    }


}
```

}

Comment: Question seems unclear. If you want dynamic data structure, use java.util.List

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should be specific and your relevant code should be [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this would be arrays. Try something like this:

```
// declarations
String[] nameAP = null;
double[] gradeAP = null;

System.out.print("Enter the number of classes you have: ");
numOfClass = Keyboard.readInt();
System.out.print("Enter the amount of AP Classes: ");
numOfAP = Keyboard.readInt();
if (numOfAP > 0)
{
    // instantiation
    nameAP = new String[numOfAP];
    gradeAP = new double[numOfAP];

    // loop
    for (int numOfAPNamed = 0; numOfAPNamed < numOfAP; ++numOfAPNamed)
    {
        System.out.printf("Enter the name of AP Class %d: ", numOfAPNamed + 1);
        // input name, percentage
        nameAP[numOfAPNamed] = Keyboard.readString();
        System.out.printf("Enter grade (in percentage) of AP Class %d: ", numOfAPNamed + );
        gradeAP[numOfAPNamed] = Keyboard.readDouble();
        System.out.println();
    }

    // TODO process...
}
```

if you cannot know the size beforehand, like reading from a file, then use a collection, like a `List` or a `Map`. See [Java Collection Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) docs fro more detail...

Comment: But how would you display the different names and grades. For example, how would I give each of the different grade percentages different letter grades, without making new variables?